# How to run node script in nuxtjs3

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I am using **nuxtjs 3** and I have a task to execute a **nodejs** script in the background, which does not depend on the client in any way. The `listen()` hook is perfect for this, but it works only in dev mode. The hook should not be triggered during nuxt build, hint, which of the hooks I can use or it is easier to really run the script execution separately.

If anyone has any queries why, the script makes a query every 3 seconds and writes data to `redis`, and the user reads data from `redis` via unstorage `useStorage()` `redis`.